# Nodejs HTTP.get() add user agent

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Im making an API in which I'm calling GET to the musicBrainz API.
Im using node.js and express.

My requests are denied because they lack a *User-Agent* (which is according to their rules: https://musicbrainz.org/doc/XML_Web_Service/Rate_Limiting)

My code:

```
const https = require('https');

    var callmbapi = function(mbid, callback, res) {
    var artistdata = '';
    const mburl = 'https://musicbrainz.org/ws/2/artist/';
    https.get(mburl + mbid + '?inc=release-groups&fmt=json', (resp) => {

        // A chunk of data has been recieved.
         resp.on('data', (chunk) => {
           artistdata += chunk;
        });
        resp.on('end', function () {
            console.log(artistdata);
        });

        }).on("error", (err) => {
            console.log("Error: " + err.message);
    });
};
```

This request worked before I reached the limit on requests without a User-Agent.

I read somewhere that I was supposed to have option which I send with the request, and have also tried:

```
const https = require('https');

const options = {
    headers: { "User-Agent": "<my user agent>" }
};

var callmbapi = function(mbid, callback, res) {
    var artistdata = '';
    const mburl = 'https://musicbrainz.org/ws/2/artist/';
    https.get(options, mburl + mbid + '?inc=release-groups&fmt=json', (resp) => {

        // A chunk of data has been recieved.
         resp.on('data', (chunk) => {
           artistdata += chunk;
        });
        resp.on('end', function () {
            console.log(artistdata);
        });

        }).on("error", (err) => {
            console.log("Error: " + err.message);
    });
};
```

But this does not work.
My question is **How do I add a User-Agent to my request?**

I am completely new to this, and have been trying to find out by myself the last 1.5h but seems that this is so basic that it is never described anywhere.

Comment: Have you checked the [Node.js documentation](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v13.x/docs/api/https.html#https_https_request_options_callback) for the `https` module? It may contain the information you are looking for. Also, what do you mean that the second attempt "does not work"? What does not work?

Comment: I checked the documentation, but do not understand how I actually add the agent, or what format it should be.
If I try the second option i get this error:
```
TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "listener" argument must be of type Function. Received type string
```
The only thing changed is that i added *options* to the https.get()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hm, according to npm, [https](https://www.npmjs.com/package/https) wasn't updated in five years.
So let's assume, you would use something newer like [axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios).
Here, the request would be like this:

```
const callmbapi = function (mbid) {
  const axios = require('axios');
  return axios
    .get('https://musicbrainz.org/ws/2/artist/' + mbid + '?inc=release-groups&fmt=json', { "User-Agent": "<my user agent>" })
    .catch(function (err) {
      console.log("Error: " + err.message); 
    });
  }
}
```

Note, that this returns a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), i.e. you need to call `.then(function (artistdata) { /* ... */ })` on the function (instead of using a callback).

With a more modern Node.js, you could use [await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) instead:

```
const callmbapi = async function (mbid) {
  const axios = require('axios');
  try {
    return axios.get('https://musicbrainz.org/ws/2/artist/' + mbid + '?inc=release-groups&fmt=json', { "User-Agent": "<my user agent>" })
  } catch(err) {
    console.log("Error: " + err.message); 
  }
}
```

Here you would `const artistdata = await callmbapi(mbid)` your data.

Comment: When you `require('https')` you actually get a [core Node.js module](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v13.x/docs/api/https.html), not something from npm registry.

Comment: Maybe https is outdated then.
But if am using axios, how do add the User-Agent to my request?

Comment: You might need to scroll horizontally, but it is the second argument:
`axios.get("<url>", { "User-Agent": "<my user agent>" })` (replace the value in angle brackets).

Comment: Oh there it is. Thank you

Comment: Note that `https` is a module that comes pre-packaged with Node.js: https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/https.js and has been updated more recently. You don't install https via npm, just `require('https')` since it's already included in the node installation by default.

Answer (score 6):

With the Node.js http(s) module, the function arguments are (url, options, callback):

```js
import https from 'https';

const options = {
    headers: {
        'User-Agent': 'some app v1.3 (example@gmail.com)',
    }
};

let body = '';
https.get('https://httpbin.org/headers', options, response => {
    console.log('status code:', response.statusCode);

    response.on('data', chunk => body += chunk);
    response.on('end', () => console.log(body + "\n"));
});
```

PS. The reason MusicBrainz asks for a User Agent is so that they contact you if your client is misbehaving.  So make sure to include your contact info in the User-Agent string.

Comment: This seems like it should be the accepted answer. It makes use of the Node https module to make the request with the optional header information.